I have problems with my functions via checkbox
I'm trying to do some of my friends a favor by automating their RPG character sheet but I'm stuck.
I would like to assign a function to a button but it wouldn't be usable on the phone, so I decided to use a checkbox but every time I try to write the formula to recall my function it says that I don't have permission to activate the setValue; the formula is this "=if("Cell number"=true; MyFunction(); " ")".
I know it's a basic thing but I can't understand where I'm wrong, I also searched the official documentation but I can't understand where I'm wrong; If anyone can help me that would be awesome
I've searched the documentation and online but no one talks about this.
I expect that when I press the checkbox it doesn't give me an error and the cell I want to modify is modified without problems

Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77492409/7215091

You can use an onedit trigger to call a function when the checkbox in a certain cell is checked.  In facr others have used this approach to run functions from their mobiles.
